# no math module python

Tags: python, math, module, compilation, xlwt

I am working in SunOS2.10.I pretty need xlwt(xlrd) modules in python(default ver. 2.4.6).In one folder of admin user, I have found Python 2.7.1, so if I write the full path to it I can use it instead of 2.4.6. I have no permission to install modules directly, so I have used command:

```
(path to ver 2.7)/python setup.py install --user
```

and module xlrd was installed without a problems. But during installation of module xlwt error occurs:

"ImportError: No module named math"

I've checked help('modules') and it lists me module "math_failed", as I understand there should be just math.
I have also tried to install this module(xlwt) using Python 2.4 but it gives me an error that:

"option --user not recognized",

so as I understand this option is not available in this python version(but math module is working there fine).

Also I was trying to install locally the whole Python using:

> > ./configure
> >
> > make altinstall prefix=~ exec-prefix=~

but it also didn't work because during 'configuration' i receive error:

"checking whether the C compiler works... no"

I don't know how to fix this problem with the compiler or how to install math module locally because I can not even find where to download it.

Please if anyone has any ideas - write me because I just stuck and have no idea what to do. Also I have to mention that I am very beginner in programming so sorry if I have write smt. stupid:) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could someone of the closers explain why this got closed? Perhaps it needs a different stackexchange site because it's about installation problems, but it's still closely related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, here's how you would install `xlwt` with Python 2.4 locally:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install --prefix=${HOME}/.local
```

Note that the `.local` directory is the default one used by the `--user` option in Python 2.6/7.

This install `xlwt`, but doesn't let you run it. Now, you'll need to set your `PYTHONPATH` correctly:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.4/site-packages
```

This assumes a `(ba)sh` type shell.

Since you would need to do this everytime you run `python` in a new shell, you're better off setting your `PYTHONPATH` in a shell source file.

And, of course, if there is already a `PYTHONPATH` set (`$ echo $PYTHONPATH` will show you), it would be

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.4/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Python 2.7 math module was badly compiled. Perhaps the C math library wasn't properly included.

On the Python 2.7 prompt, try:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.__file__
```

Then, with that filename, on the command line (outside Python), try

```
$ ldd <filename>
```

(Note: I don't know if `ldd` exists on Sun OS; otherwise, I hope you know the equivalent.)
Verify that libm is there. For example, on my Linux machine, I see

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffaffff000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3326ccf000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3326ab3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3326750000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3327180000)
```

If you se it missing, try to find it on the system and set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or Sun OS equivalent to the directory `libm` lives in, then try `ldd <filename>` again.

If that works this time, try installing `xlwt` again. Just keep in mind you would always need to have your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or equivalent set (e.g., through a shell source file).

Comment: SunOS [does have ldd](http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaman/hman1/ldd.1.html) just as an FYI

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.
 Actually I can not just check math.__file__ because I can not import math in python 2.7("No module named math"), but I have checked in python2.4 where this module is and open appropriate dir. for 2.7. But there I have found only math_failed.so file. I am not sure if there is anywhere in the system the correct math.so file. For me it looks just like it is corrupted.

Comment: But can I install 'default' python module (in my case "math") separately as a local module? So this broken one - will remain, but I will have locally, working one?

Comment: @tarastd I'm afraid not. The math module is pretty intrinsic to Python. If anything, you would need to compile a Python 2.7 yourself, but since your C compiler doesn't work, that won't work. You can copy the 2.4 math module, but I'm guessing the versioning is such that that may mess up Python 2.7 when it uses it.